# Why to use mocha rails? Whats that for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I'm so confused about using mocha. We want to test how method works so defining return variables is like cheating?
So far I understand mocha like using example below...

> assert_equal 5, 2+3

...instead of

> assert_equal 5, add(2,3)

whats mocha for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mocha is a library for mocking and stubbing](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/).  From what you have posted, it looks like you are dealing with Test::Unit and not using Mocha at all.  Try reading the Mocha [README](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) to get a better understanding of Mocha's capabilities.  Mocking and stubbing are advanced concepts, so it might be better to focus on plain Test::Unit until you are more familiar with testing.